# Existence of a local spinor bundle

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, spin-geometry, index-theory

I am confused about the existence of a local spinor bundle.

My question is that if a Riemannian manifold $M$ is not spin, why does there exist a local spinor bundle over all sufficiently small open subsets of $M$?

I'm not sure if it is too easy on Mathoverflow. Could you give me some help with the details? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Sufficiently small (say contractible ones), open subsets of $M$ are themselves spin manifolds. So doesn't your first sentence already answer your second sentence?

Comment: @IgorKhavkine I edited my question again.

Comment: Are you talking about how you can construct the bundle directly out of inhomogeneous sums of differential forms as in J. Math. Phys. 37, 3882 (1996) https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.531607 ?

Comment: The existence of a spin-structure and thus an associated spinor bundle is purely topological and obstructed by the first and second Stiefel-Whitney-class, which vanish in your situation, since you have sufficiently small open subsets, which we can be choosen contractible.